# Windows file position in folder

Tags: count, directory

I need to view position of file in folder for example "abc.txt" is on 67 line in folder is there option in windows or some other program?

Comment: In what? from what? on what? Based on what sorting criteria?

Comment: folder with lot of files sorting does not matter (it can be by alphabet/date/size....)  for example I need to move files on 241,321,85...   position to another directory.